# Why is it printing "hurrah" even when the condition are false?

Tags: python, python-3.x

[image]

The highlighted part of the code is telling me to "remove redundant parentheses", but when I remove them, there is a syntax error regarding the comma.

Comment: you don't need a comma in between. Remove the parentheses and have an and condition

Comment: With the parentheses, the interpreter treat is as a tuple (python doesn't need parentheses around the condition) so you actually check for `if some_tuple`. Now, if that tuple is not empty, it will always be true. To fix it, just change the comma to an `and`.

Comment: Also, you should post the code here, not an image of the code

Comment: @בנימיןכהן Thank you, I was looking for this explanation and I will keep in mind to post the code here itself.

Answer (score 4):

The parentheses and the comma is making the interpreter thinking that the condition a tuple, which then evaluates to (False, False), and python treats tuple with any elements as true.[More info about tuples here](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_tuples.asp)
To fix this, you have to replace the "," with a boolean operator depending on the situation.

Answer (score 2):

you have to use and/or while u adding two conditions also `a==9` included in the condition `a>4` so no need of `a==9`

```
a=4
if(a>5 or a==9):
    print ("hurrah")
```

Answer (score 1):

you should use and / or instead of comma and remove brackets

```
if a > 5 or a == 9:
    print('hurray')
```